# go back to vim's default color

Tags: vim, vimrc

I read this `:highlight Normal ctermfg=grey ctermbg=darkblue` from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117526/setting-the-vim-background-colors

But I change the darkblue to white!! What I done? OMG? now I even can not see what I type on vim on the command mode. please tell me how to tell vim to use its default coloring.

Comment: the problem solved! when I type  :highlight Normal ctermfg=grey ctermbg=white  on the command mode on vim. that is temporary. I type :q! and quit. for the nest time the color come back to its default.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing Vim editor settings?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/264258/changing-vim-editor-settings)

Answer (score 0):

While this is not Ubuntu specific, a similar question is [264258](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264258/changing-vim-editor-settings). Just like you edit `~/.vimrc` before, put in your own commands:

> set background=dark
>   highlight Normal ctermfg=grey ctermbg=white

The help file might can give you more background.

> :help vimrc-intro